# Linear Algebra - linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a set of vectors in $V$. Define $S^0$ to be the set of linear functional that vanishes on $S$.

Show that $$S^0  = \langle S\rangle^0$$

I am really confused what is meant by $S^0$

Comment: $S^0$ is defined to be the set of linear functionals that vanish on $S$.

Comment: Using mathematical notation, perhaps?

Comment: aka the annihilator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S^0=\{f:V\to\Bbb R \mid \forall s\in S: f(s)=0\}$.

Show that, if $f\in S^0$ then $f\in \langle S\rangle^0$ and the other way around, if
$g\in \langle S\rangle^0$ then $g\in S^0$. (One of these is trivial, the other follows by linearity.)

Answer (score 1):

A linear functional on $V$ is a linear map
$$
f\colon V\to K
$$
where $K$ is the base field (in your case it may be the reals or the complex numbers, please add details), where $K$ is considered as a vector space.

The set of linear functionals on $V$ is usually denoted by $V^*$; so

$$
S^0=\{f\in V^* : f(x)=0,\text{ for all }x\in S\}
$$

Now, set $T=\langle S\rangle$, the subspace spanned by $S$. It is rather easy showing that
$$
T^0\subseteq S^0
$$
because $S\subseteq T$. For the converse inclusion, take $f\in S^0$ and try showing that, for all $x\in T$, it must be $f(x)=0$ (that is, $f\in T^0$).

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$$f\in S^0\iff\;\forall\,s\in S\;,\;\;f(s)=0$$

What you have to prove is that a linear functional (i.e., an element of $\;V^*$) vanishes on a set $\;S\;$ iff it vanishes on the *vector subspace* that set generates, for example

$$f(s)=0\;\;\forall\,s\in S\implies \;\forall\;\text{linear combination}\;\sum_{i=1}^m a_
is_i\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb F\;,\;$$

$$s_i\in S\;,\;\;f\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_is_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^ma_if(s_i)=0 \;(\text{fill in details})$$